# Creating join entities from a form

Tags: php, symfony

I have three entities, `User`, `Provider` and `UserProvider` (a join entity with some extra data).

I'm trying to create a form where the user specifies their providers by ticking boxes (which should generate some `UserProvider` records).

I've tried using choices and generating a new form type but can't seem to get it working correctly. This is the last thing I tried:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
    ->add('userProviders', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyAppBundle:UserProvider',
        'property' => 'provider.name'
        'choices' => $userProviders
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

Where `$userProviders` is an array of some entities I generated mapping the current user to all possible providers, but this won't work because the entities are not persisted (as they may not be needed).

What is the cleanest way to do this in Symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to this I just created a unbound form listing `Providers` and persisted them, along with the current `User` as `UserProviders`.

This isn't ideal, as revisiting the form won't show the existing join entities (`UserProvider`) and additional work is needed to make those visible.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the internal way of the entity form class to generate your array like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...

$builder->add('userProviders', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyAppBundle:UserProvider',
    'property' => 'provider.name'
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            //Your Query here
        ;
    },
));
```

Taken from here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html

You can do everything you want inside there, even 2 queries for possible `NOT IN` cases.

Comment: Thank you, but what is it that would be queried since there are currently no ``UserProvider``s?

Comment: You want to query for the providers you want the user to choose from. Pretty much the query you used to get your `UserProvider` array in the OP.

Comment: The query needs to return a ``UserProvider`` set which is different from ``Provider``. ``UserProvider`` is the join entity.
The array was made from me looping over the current ``Provider`` objects and creating ``UserProvider`` objects along with the current ``User``s id, giving the possible choices.

Comment: Then just use your type as a service, injecting the repository you need and do all your single joins and other queries in the repository.
This way you should be able to get everything you want, just yesterday I did a query joining over 2 tables and 2 subqueries in the querybuilder.